# Multiple CountDownTimers with a uiversal Cancel command

Tags: android, timer, countdowntimer

Im back to ask another question :)

In an app I am making, I need a selector to choose one of 4 different countdown timers, for example round1, round2, etc.

but i have 2 problems with the same source. Using the default countdowntimer implentation which doesnt involve naming it round1 but running as a straight countdowntimer, I can cancel it in onPause using
    coutdowntimer.cancel();

but after naming it round1 I can no longer pause it and the round1.cancel(); comes up as undefined.

I have spent most of yesterday and throught to 3am trying to find a solution and i thought i had it by making my timers final but it still didnt work.

after thinking about it more i relaised once ive solved this problem, I'm going to have to implement an if statement in my onpause which i would rather not do in an effort to keep my code clean.

So is there a way to implement a universal cancel command to cancel the root countdowntimer function regardless of the actual name its running under. 
for example

```
public void canceltimers(){
//if round1,2,3,4 is runnng, cancel the main countdowntimer thread altogether. 
countdowntimer.Cancel();
}
```

any help is appreciated and here is my current timer code.

```
CountDownTimer round1 = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            textview4.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
          endsequence();
        }
          };

         CountDownTimer round2 = new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         textview4.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
              }

         public void onFinish() {
         endsequence();
              }
                };
   // round1.start();
```

ive not implemented my if statements for the level select yet but will be similar to this

```
 if (level == 1){
 round1.start();}
 if (level == 2){
 round2.start();}
```

So far i have tried setting it as final, with no joy. 
I have tried

```
round1.cancel();
```

with no joy. as well every implementation of countdowntimer i can think of or find.

Now as a request, im not as amazing as making sense of code as most of you guys so if you could try and give an example of the implementation it would be appreciated, Thanks for looking and thanks for your time & help

phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a single timer. Add multiple timertasks to this timer. Define the COUNTDOWN_TIME.

```
Timer mTimer = new Timer();

mTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   //execute code when the COUNTDOWN_TIME has ran out.
                }
            }, COUNTDOWN_TIME);
        }

//cancels all sceduled/running TimerTasks
mTimer.cancel();
```

Comment: would COUNTDOWN_TIME be a long? such as int long COUNTDOWN_TIME = 30000;

Comment: COUNTDOWN_TIME is a long (expressed in milisecons); Don't use numbers as 30000, but set them as 5 * 60 * 1000 (= 5 minutes, makes it easier to read).

Comment: thanks for the advice, Would i be right to implement them in the manner I said though?

Comment: I don't know about that

Comment: ok no worrys, will experiment and update my question to include a walthrough. thanks a bunch and answer is accepted. take care JorenV